# Integrating an ASP.NET MVC application with OpenAM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openam

Does anyone have or know of any example of integrating an **ASP.NET MVC** application with **OpenAM**?
I have an application deployed with **ASP.NET MVC 2** where the authentication is perforned using forms authentication, and I need to change into authentication using **Single Sign On** via OpenAM.
I've been searching for a code example of OpenAM integration from .NET, but I have found almost nothing so far. A code example would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to accomplish this scenario over SAML protocol, then it is not problematic.
You have to download and install OpenAM on Tomcat Appache server. Configure it. Then on page [.Net Fedlet](http://openam.forgerock.org/openam-documentation/openam-doc-source/doc/dev-guide/index/chap-fedlet-dotnet.html) you can find details about the .Net Fedlet. That is library set and application sample written on .Net, how to adjust your asp.net application to target OpenAM server. This library supports SAMLP from your web application.

What I am looking for and I have not found yet is the same scenario but over WS-Federation and with usage of WIF. If I found out how I will write it here.